# Stepper motor linked to shaft: let shaft move freely until I signal the stepper motor to move the shaft

Tags: dc-motor, stepper-motor

I have a shaft attached to a stepper motor. I want the shaft to move up and down freely until I trigger a signal and then move the shaft with the stepper motor. Is this possible with only the stepper motor and without an engage/disengage mechanism?

Comment: Have you ever played with a stepper motor and experienced the "cogging" resistance as you turn the shaft of the unpowered motor? Is that amount of cogging acceptable?

Comment: How "freely" do you need it to be? If you don't power the motor it can be moved "by hand", but there is still detent torque do be overcome. How much depends on the stepper motor, but it won't be zero.

Answer (score 2):

When a stepper motor is un-powered, there is a small residual torque required to turn it, called 'cogging'. This could be relatively large if the motor uses a permanent magnet rotor and salient iron poles. It will be smaller if it's an all-iron 'reluctance' motor, and there's only the residual magnetism in the iron rotor to try to hold it in position. In either case, this un-powered torque ought to be an order of magnitude below the torque it can generate when powered.

It's up to your application whether this residual torque is low enough for you or not. If it's critical, try several different motor types, some will be lower cogging torque than others.